# error in SQL syntax using prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String select = "select script from kit where (name = ?) and (creator = ?)";
PreparedStatement prepared = db.prepareStatement(select);
prepared.setString(1, name);
prepared.setInt(2, creator);
ResultSet result = prepared.executeQuery(select);
```

gives me an "error in your SQL syntax"

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) and (creator = ?)' at line 1

What's going on? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either JDBC or your underlying database does not like the terms in the `WHERE` clause being in parentheses.  Try removing them:

```
String select = "select script from kit where name = ? and creator = ?";
PreparedStatement prepared = db.prepareStatement(select);
prepared.setString(1, name);
prepared.setInt(2, creator);
ResultSet result = prepared.executeQuery();
```

Note also that `PreparedStatement#executeQuery()` does not take any parameters.  Since you have already prepared the statement and bound the parameters, you only need to execute that query.

I am surprised that MySQL is complaining about this, because from what I saw testing here locally, your current query should execute without any problems.

Comment: same error happens

Comment: Then my guess is that you are not executing the above code.  Anyway, my answer resolved another problem in your code.